# Can a Jew sell a sefer Torah to a non-Jew? Why or why not?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, transactions, sefer-torah

A question was raised [whether a non-Jew can run a Judaica store](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23515/can-a-nonjew-run-a-judaica-store).  My thought on that was it depended on what types of judaica he sold.  I doubted that a sofer would sell him mezuzah parchments, tefillin or sefer Torahs.  Also, I saw a video of a church using a sefer Torah in its services (opening it up from end to end and wrapping it around congregants; oy!) Is there a halachic prohibition to selling a sefer Torah to a non-Jew?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the Halachos of Mezuza:

see `Rambam (sefer ahava - Hilchos Tefillin, Mezuza, v'Sefer Torah - Chapter 5:11)`

you will find that it is forbidden, when moving out of an apartment, to leave a Mezuza there if a gentile will be moving in. The reason given is that he may come to desecrate it.

Also, see `Ramah (Yoreh De'ah 291:2)`

Who states that it is forbidden to give a mezuzah to a gentile to affix on his door.

We may be able to infer from here the Halachos of selling a Torah to Gentiles. If we are worried they will desecrate it, it is probably not allowed. (Wrapping it around the congregants is surely a desecration!)

Having said that, I have heard from an Orthodox Rabbi, that selling a Mezuzah to a gentile can be permissible today if we are not worried they will come to desecrate it. (there are plenty of Gentiles out there who are aware of the spiritual benefits of Mezuza and would be happy to affix one on their door)

Comment: related discussion about mezuzot and non-Jews http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17808/759

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the comment of @shnozolla that the daf of the SA continues
(כך השיב מהרי"ל) ונראה לי דמ"מ במקום דאיכא למיחש משום איבה ושירע משום זה לישראל שרי (כנ"ל):

Maharil: But it seems to me that this applies in a case where there is reason to be concerned that in that particular place there will be hostility [towards Jews if one does not give the mezuzah to the idol worshiper], and that the idol worshiper will treat Jews poorly because of this, it is permissible [to give a mezuzah to an idol worshipper].