# eBay Judaica auctions

Tags: halacha, gentiles, tefilin, transactions, mezuzah

I occasionally check eBay for assorted items; this is typically for the science half of my life, but I sometimes find [Judaica](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ANTIQUE-TEFILLIN-Jewish-Hebrew-Art-Scroll-Parchment-Manuscript-EUROPE-circa-1850-/221393612946?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item338c167092) which probably should not be sold there. For example, I know that in the case of a sefer torah, there is an obligation to purchase, rather than letting it go to a non-Jew. Does this always apply and furthermore, does it apply to purchasing other sta"m (holy scribe-written) products?

Comment: How do "[you] know that in the case of a sefer torah, there is an obligation to purchase, rather than letting it go to a nochri"?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23520/can-a-jew-sell-a-sefer-torah-to-a-non-jew-why-or-why-not

Comment: @DoubleAA, I read an article some time ago about a Jekkish sefer which was being auctioned on a shabbat, and the author was given express permission by his rav to bid in advance or purchase after shabbat, so as not to let the torah go to goyim; I do not recall where this was, I believe it was a safrus blog. The Torah, it turns out was pasul to begin with and would have needed several thousand US$ worth of repairs for leyning.

Comment: How do you prove from there that there is an obligation? Perhaps it is just a Mitzva. IAE you should always cite your claims as much as you can in the question body.

Comment: My attempts to dig up a single page about sta"m in a history filled with such entries.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt the story you're thinking of must surely be from this blog: http://lavlor.blogspot.ca/2013/05/auction-sefer-torah.html

Comment: @DoubleAA MB 39:17 says that one is required to purchase it