# Selling Gemara to non-Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, jewish-books, business, transactions

Is it permissible for someone to sell sefarim (e.g., a gemara) to non-Jews?

Does it make a difference if they are messianic "Jews" (people who believe Jesus is Moshiach)?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)

Hope to see you around!

Comment: Also you might find MY's official tour to be helpful https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36867/11501

Comment: I wonder what a Messianic Jew would want with a Gemara.

Comment: Related:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23520/501 - Can a Jew sell a sefer Torah to a non-Jew? Why or why not?

Comment: @ezra - in days long past "Messianic Jews" used Gemaras and other seforim as fuel for their alleged "disputations" in Paris, Barcelona, etc.

Comment: @Gary Good luck if any Messianic Jew could even read the Gemara... None of them have training save those who grew up in Orthodox homes, went to yeshiva, etc. but those are few and far between.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely need to ask a rav. It is possible this is permitted in case of non-Jews who will handle the *sefarim* with respect but likely this is NOT permitted in case of messianic Jews.

Two relevant sources you might consider when asking are

- dinonline [writes](http://dinonline.org/2014/08/02/selling-tefillin-to-non-jew/) the prohibition of selling *tefilin* and similar items to non-Jews is out of concern for disrespect to the item. If there is no concern they will handle with disrespect (the case there is a person in the process of conversion), it is fine to sell them

HOWEVER

- elsewhere dinonline [mentions](http://dinonline.org/2012/10/23/giving-mezuzah-to-non-jew/) the Rema and Maharil in SA [YD 291:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.291.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that forbids handing over a mezuza to a non-Jew. They cite lenient rulings but, when discussing the reasons this is forbidden write that **people will think that the non-Jew is Jewish** (the assumption, based on [Menachot 43a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.43a.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), is that **this confusion is liable to endanger Jews)**.

The latter could be exactly the scenario of Messianic Jews using these gemarot to spiritually endanger other Jews.

Again, [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before acting on what you read here.